# Преобразование HTML в PDF с помощью PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf

Посоветуйте хорошую библиотеку, которая умеет парсить HTML в формат PDF средствами PHP и понимает русскоязычные шрифты. Перепробовал кучу всего, но оптимального варианта не нашел. Остановился на tFPDF, но она не умеет работать с HTML разметкой и приходится рисовать таблицы вручную. Кто сталквался с таким? Есть решение?

Comment: вы опишите какие у вас требования к библиотеке, и чем вам не устроили те, что вы перебрали (и какие) а то по второму разу какой толк советовать. Например, чем вас не устроило первая ссылка из гугла про `dompdf` ?

Comment: dompdf у меня ни в какую не хотел распознавать кириллические шрифты, как и большинство библиотек типа fpdf, mpdf html2pdf. tfpdf со шрифтами подружил, но HTML он парсить не умеет.

Comment: у вас там `utf` было, или что-то другое?

Comment: utf, windows-1251 пробовал

Comment: я вроде как-то делал что-то с `dompdf` и он вполне подружился без особых проблем с русским языком.

Comment: teran, рабочая директория с ним осталась? можешь поделиться?

Comment: в целом могу глянуть, но в настоящий момент что-то не могу подключиться к рабочей сети и добраться до кода.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf  - умеет в стили, шрифты)

Comment: Сам нашел решение для своей проблемы. Библиотека TCPDF прям из коробки работает с кириллицей, есть шрифт, поддерживающий кириллицу (dejavusans), и с HTML тоже работает отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php). Также можно воспользоваться на сервере библиотекой `wkhtmltopdf`.